# How to Solve General Vector-Valued First Order Linear PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ and consider the system of $k$ equations
$$
 \sum_{i=1,\dots,n; j=1,\dots,k}
 \xi^{(m)}_{i,j}
 \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_k}
 =
 f_m,
$$
with $m$ ranging from $1$ to $k$, where $\xi^{(m)}_{i,j} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are some functions.

> Is there a general theory for the solution of such systems of equations?

As a matter of fact, my case is particularly easy:
here we have $\xi^{(m)}_{i,j} \in \{-1,0,1\}$.
In fact, so many of them are zero that it is not difficult to guess a family of solutions.
But I would like to find all possible solutions.

In my case I also have $n=k=6$, so the problem is not extraordinarily high-dimensional.
I am also happy if someone can suggest computational solution that will give me a family of approximated solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general theory for the solution of such PDEs is the theory of *Exterior Differential Systems*.
The method of *Cartan-Kähler Calculus* works in the real-analytic category, which was enough for my purposes.

The monograph *Bryant, R.L., Chern, S.S., Gardner, R.B., Goldschmidt, H.L., Griffiths, P.A.: Exterior Differential Systems* gives an introduction to the theory.
An example in the spirit of my question is executed on pages 60-63.

The *DifferentialGeometry* package of the mathematical software *Maple* has these exterior differential systems implemented, and my problem can be solved using the *IntegralManifold* method.
In fact, even the standard method *pdsolve* is powerful enough to solve such systems.